# Broadleaf Commerce: Getting started MVN install errors

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mycompany-community:boot-community-demo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.broadleafcommerce:broadleaf-boot-starter-parent:pom:5.2.1-SNAPSHOT from/to public snapshots (http://nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/groups/community-snapshots/): Connect to nexus.broadleafcommerce.org:80 [nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/104.130.140.202] failed: Connection timed out: connect and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 13

I am new to Broadleaf & am a UI Developer. I am trying to setup 'Heat Clinic Demo' in my local but unable to do so. Am getting the above errors and unable to proceed further, can someone please help me out in running the project. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you got that version for your parent but it should be version 5.2.2.1-GA. That is our latest release version. I recommend changing the root pom.xml to use that version instead (in the  element).

The Maven error indicates that it could not connect to the Broadleaf nexus. On my end it looks like it is up, verify that you can ping it and try again with -U, e.g. mvn clean install -U to force metadata to be refreshed from the nexus.